# Objective-C append dictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

i need to send data to server with NSDictionary. The data will be name, gender dll, is coming from text field. I know i can save one dictionary like this.

```
NSDictionary * = @{@"employee": @"EmpA",
                             @"gender":@"Male",
                             @"pob":@"SF",
                             @"age":@"27",
                             };
```

But i need to add multiple data because i have button that can repeat the form procedure. After that i will send the whole data to server based on format below.

```
"employee": [{
    "name": "EmpA",
    "gender": "Male",
    "pob": "SF",
    "age": 27
    }, {
    "name": "EmpB",
    "gender": "Female",
    "pob": "TX",
    "age": 36
    }]
```

How i can dynamically append the dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: Use `NSMutableArray` to hold multiple dictionaries

Comment: as rckoenes has said you need to the use the Mutable version. In General You will be using `NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableDictionary`, `NSMutableString`, `NSMutableRequest`, etc a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use an Array of dictionaries :

```
NSMutableArray *employees= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(//loop through the forms) {
    NSDictionary *emp = @{@"name": @"EmpA",
                       @"gender":@"Male",
                       @"pob":@"SF",
                       @"age":@"27",
                      };
    [employees addObject:emp];
}

NSDictionary *payload = @{@"employee": employees};
```

I dont have a mac at hand so forgive any syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of dictionaries and insert it in your "employee" key. Something like this should work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *employee = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *emplyeeA = [@{@"name": @"EmpA", @"gender": @"Male", @"pob": @"SF", @"age": @"27"} mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *emplyeeB = [@{@"name": @"EmpB", @"gender": @"Female", @"pob": @"TX", @"age": @"36"} mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObject: emplyeeA];
[tempArray addObject: emplyeeB];
[employee setObject:tempArray forKey:@"employee"];
```

Comment: you dont need to request mutableCopy again for emplyeeA & B